# Write javascript to detect click event in li

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I have li something like this.This code is from some website and I don't have permission to modify that code.

```
<li class="History_lisitem_logout ui-last-child" data-icon="power">
                        <a id="History_lisitem_logout" name="lisitem_logout" dsid="lisitem_logout" tabindex="2" class="History_lisitem_logout ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-power">
                        <h3>Sign Out</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

I need to call that website from my ios or android app and if user click on that li, i need to trigger my own native code.

If it is normal button, I can easily do like this to call my native code.

```
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "$(document).on('touchstart', '#History_lisitem_logout', function() {window.location = 'ios:logoutGleer';});")
```

However, the issue is that I don't have 'id' in 'li' and I cannot inject my javascript code to detect event for clicking 'li'. How shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tag has id; make use of it.

```
let listEl = document.getElementById("History_lisitem_logout").parentElement
```

Comment: thanks. after I get listEl, how can I call window.location ? Sorry i am not very good at this.

Comment: window.location is usually used to navigate to a particular website; For ex if you open your browser console and type this,  window.location = "http://www.google.co.in" ;  end hit enter your browser will take you to google

Comment: yes. i need to trigger onclick for listEl. When it is clicked, I need to call window.location.

Comment: window.location to where?

Comment: To something like this. window.location = 'ios:logoutGleer' . It will help me to call my native ios code.

Comment: Yes I saw your code; But I am not an ios person; so I dont know if window.location will work for you. Sry abt that.

Comment: It is okay. If I write something like this, is it correct? listEl.onclick = function(){window.location = 'ios:logoutGleer';};

Comment: from js perspective, nothing wrong with it. give it  a try